# Trying to make a txt file of a list using a webpart

Tags: web-part, error

I'm using a sandboxed solution, this is the error I got when I try to make the txt

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed. sharepoint

This is the code I have for creating and writting on the file

```
string path = @"C:\pruebas\" + txtNombre.Text + ".txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))//here happens the error
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Hello");
                sw.WriteLine(Texto);
            }
        }
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            string s = "";
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
```

Comment: try without the `@`, which using means a literal string. Try to spit out the path variable to make sure it is valid.

Comment: You don't have access to file system from Sandboxed Solution. It is blocked, hence sandboxed

Comment: I made it a farm solution, and works now, but the problem is that the .txt file is created on the server and not on the user pc

Answer (score 0):

If you need full trust operations in sandboxed code, you can create and use [sandbox proxies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg622616), as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff798427.aspx), [here](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2009-12-SharePoint_2010_Sandboxed_Solutions__Full_Trust__Proxies.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/472824/Implementing-a-Sandbox-Proxy-in-SharePoint).